# How to make FFXIV chat sticky from typing?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

In Final Fantasy Online (FFXIV) when I'm in a party and type `/p Hello`, the chat mode does not stick to "Party", but remains on the previous one instead. This makes my next message appear in the old channel:

[image: chat example]

I can *click* on the talking bubble icon to make chat stick to another channel, but I'd like the game to remember a channel from my previous `/` message. Can that be done?

I've gone through the "Character Configuration" > "Log Window Setting" configuration, but haven't found any such option yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no sticky chat command... however, there is a simple chat command to switch the default chat mode.

Send `/p` or `/party` without any chat text to switch the default chat mode to party.  This also works for `/say`, `/yell`, `/alliance`, `/freecompany` and many others.

It also works with `/tell` if you supply a player name.

Comment: while @IG_42 has been downvoted, what he says about shout is true for this method too

Answer (score -1):

Just click on that speech bubble and pick which channel you want to use, works for everything except shout.